# windows service works on Debug (F5) but not when installed

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a Windows service that is written in C# it works fine when i press F5 and generates the required files and directories  but nothing happens (files and directories are not generated) when I install it using installutil.exe. The service installs fine and status is running

tried writing logs to the file (log file is empty)
attached a debugger. (point breaks on the onstart() and initialization are not getting hit) 
double check the service name in the installer  (this is fine)
checked event viewer logs (nothing related to .Net or service is shown)

none of this seems to point me to the right direction please help

here is the code snippet

```
     public void OnStartLive(string[] args)
        {

            Init();

        }

         private void Init()
        {
        // generates the file and directories
        }

         protected override void OnStop()
        {


            DeInit();
        }



namespace filesGerator
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            if (System.Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                if (args.Length > 0)
                {
                    switch (args[0])
                    {
                        case "-install":
                            {
                                ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                                break;
                            }
                        case "-uninstall":
                            {
                                ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
                else
                {


                        var oService = new miFileGeneratorServer();
                        oService.OnStartLive(null);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);


                }
            }
            else
            {
                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new miFileGeneratorServer() 
            };
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the service user account have the appropriate rights to the target files?

Comment: Please post some code for your service. In addition to @stuartd commented, there could be any number of issues.

Comment: @stuartd yes I have used localSystem account and set the username and password to null so it doesnt prompt for them

Comment: .. and so the target files are local? Also is there anything relevant in the System event log?

Comment: @stuartd yes the files needs to be generated on my local PC, there's nothing related to this on the eventviewer

Comment: Are you doing the actual work in OnStart? If you are, then this will not work, as the Service Control Manager requires OnStart to return promptly. You need to return from OnStart ASAP and _then_ do the file work via a thread, background process, or async task.